# Common lisp: run shell command containing the string "\n"

Tags: linux, shell, common-lisp, newline, sbcl

I'm trying to run something that simplifies to

`(trivial-shell:shell-command 
  (concatenate 'string "echo -e " "one" "\n" "two"))`

And trying to get it to return something like

`"one
two"`

Whereas what it returns instead is

`"onentwo
"`

I'd be open to using something different from trivial-shell (I've tried inferior-shell, but it had the same problem)

Using SBCL 1.1.18 on 64-bit Gentoo Linux

Comment: A backslash escapes the next character. If you want a backslash character in the string, you have to escape it with another backslash `"\\n"`.

Comment: you must backslash your backslashes in strings

Comment: Doesn't work either, the result is the same. It's the same for three backslashes also.

Four backslashes works in the example I gave in the question, but doesn't work in the actual code - I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: You're also lacking quotes around the string in the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to output a newline is to have a newline character inside your string:

```
(print "one
two")
```

You can also coerce the newline character into a string:

```
(concatenate 'string "one" (string #\newline) "two")
```

You cannot use `\n` in a string to insert newlines: the backslash is only used to escape double-quotes inside strings (e.g. `"\""`). Necessarily, it is used to escape actual backslashes character too.
So if you want to print a backslash followed by `n`, you need to escape the backslash:

```
(print "\\n")
```

But then, why do you need 4 backslashes?

Because `trivial-shell:shell-command` invokes a shell, as given by `*bourne-compatible-shell*`, and gives it a command as a string. And so, your string might be subject to shell escaping rules too.

```
(trivial-shell:shell-command "echo -e one \\\\n two")
```

Knowing that, you might want to take into account the fact that bourne compatible shells have single-quotes, which do not require escaping characters inside of them. The following works as expected:

```
(trivial-shell:shell-command "echo 'one 
two'")
```

Note that the default value for `trivial-shell:*bourne-compatible-shell*` is `"/bin/sh"`, which as far as I know does not recognize the `-e` option for `echo`. You might already know this, but you might want to use a different shell. Here is a program that calls `echo` with newlines between arguments:

```
(defun echo-args (&rest args)
  (let ((trivial-shell:*bourne-compatible-shell* #P"/bin/bash"))
    (trivial-shell:shell-command
     (format nil "echo -e '~{~A~^~%~}'" args))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using four backslashes instead of one.